# Choosing between two methods of screen capturing in C#

Tags: c#, image, screenshot, trim, crop

**The purpose of my Program is to capture multiple areas on the screen.** I'm choosing between 2 methods to write this program:

1. Making one big screenshot 800x600 for further cropping (10+ areas)
2. Or making multiple **Small** screenshots with given coordinates. (10+)

**what's better in terms of performance?**

another question which is also related to this question is:

**where do I keep all crop coordinates?** I'll need at least one Column to specify numbering, Next two columns will have X and Y coordinates and last two - W and H. I was thinking about making a dictionary for a separate crop.. or maybe a table, SQL, INI, array ?? that's the second question. Easiness of use and performance are top priorities.

thanks

**Edit: Rephrasing the question.** What's faster - To capture a screenshot of whole screen and Crop it into 100 small areas (W:10 & H:100) OR to capture 100 small Screenshots without the need to crop anything?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Ease of use for who?

Comment: what is your purpose?  what exactly is your program supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to Crop screenshot OR capture Multiple small screenshots.

Comment: It sounds like @usr has the right idea.  This is *super* easy to test.  pull out your `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` and get on it ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to measure this. We can't know the answer without trying. It also probably depends on the exact count and sized of the screenshot areas.

Comment: ok I'll run some tests regarding this issue, but what about place where I can store pixel sizes? (numbers, coordinates, sizes)

Comment: After all I've decided to store them in Int array.